# Passing date sql type in prepared statement with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, web-hosting

I'm using 000webhost to host my website.

I'm trying to implement this flow:

1. Receive file about a given date and shift;
2. Delete any information about that date and shift that exists in the database;
3. Insert the received information;

I'm having trouble with step two. The code I'm using is this:

```
 $cleanupSql = "DELETE FROM `Turnos` WHERE Dia = :Dia AND Turno  = :Turno ";

 $cleanupSth = $conn->prepare($cleanupSql);

 (...)
 $temp = date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
 $cleanupSth->bindParam(':Dia',$temp,PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $cleanupSth->bindParam(':Turno',$splited[2],PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $cleanupSth->execute();
```

$temp is equal to 2018-10-18 and splited[2] is "1". dia of type date and Turno of type varchar. PHP doesn't present any errors, but the database is not changed.

I've also tried to use ? params, passing the dateTime object.

When I run this query in the database, which , it works

```
 DELETE FROM `Turnos` WHERE Dia = "2018-08-18" AND Turno  = "1"
```

EDIT: I've modified the script to run the query like so:

```
$cleanupSql = "DELETE FROM `Turnos` WHERE Turno  = :Turno ";
```

But it doesn't reflect on the database.

Comment: `2018-10-18` and `2018-08-10` are not the same date. Have you tried running the query in the database with `Dia = "2018-10-18"`?

Comment: `2018-10-18` != `2018-08-10"`

Comment: It was a typo when writing the question. Sorry..

Comment: Can you show the query ? ($cleanupSth->queryString())

Comment: It does not return anything different. DELETE FROM `Turnos` WHERE Dia = :Dia AND Turno = :Turno. Is it ->queryString?

Comment: Does `$cleanupSth->execute();` return true or false? That way you'll know if the query crashed or not. Also is the "Turno" column in your database an int or a varchar? And the obvious-but-you-should-double-check questions: do you definitely have any values in the database which have the relevant ID and should be deleted? Is your code connecting to the same database as the one you're looking at?

Comment: one of the reason it is not deleting will be foreign key constraints with other tables.

Comment: execute() returns 1, so true. Turno is a varchar(50). I switched the user to the one which the website uses and no problem in the phpMyAdmin and had no problems executing the query. I just double-checked again the conf file and it seems ok.

Comment: In that case as far as I can see the only possible reasons for it not deleting anything is either the Turno value being passed into the DB is not what you think it is, and/or simply there are no matching rows with that Turno number in the database which the PHP script is connected to. Unfortunately none of those are things we can help you with just from looking at your code...you'd have to double check it all yourself.

Comment: Ok.. So I tried to do delete without anything and it worked. Then I introduced only the Turno it does not work. Only the date works, so the problem comes indeed from the Turno column.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the way I was getting the information for the Turno param. It was not correctly sanitized.